# Processing- how can I make my boolean stay fixed for longer?

Tags: javascript, boolean, processing

A student processing/javascript amateur looking for some advice on a game I have made. It has been made in Processing 2.2.1 which I believe is relatively outdated so some names for variables etc may vary.

What I believe the issue to be is that during a collision event (with the character and an object that gives it an extra life), the 'life' boolean is set to true however only for the duration of the collision. I want the boolean to be set to true until the character then collides with an object that would usually end the game. My current setup means that the character has an extra life momentarily so will always die when it comes into contact with a bad object.

I have attached some of my code. Any advice?`

```js
  //Part of the 'good object' code:
  
  void Draw()
  {
    image(Warning_fall, Position.x, 130);
    Hat.resize(86, 66);

    if (life == true)
    {
      image(Hat, 170, 50);
    } else
    {
      image(Hat, Position.x, Position.y);
    }
  }

  void Move()
  {
    Position.add(Velocity);
  }

  boolean hatHit(float x, float y, float w, float h)   
  {
    if ((x < Position.x) && (x + w > Position.x + 86) && (y + h > Position.y) && (y + h > Position.y + 66))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
} 

//From the main game code

for (int index = 0; index < num_of_hats; index ++)
    {  
      arrayHats[index].Draw();
      arrayHats[index].Move();
      if (arrayHats[index].hatHit(Students.sx, Students.sy, sw, sh) == true)
      {
        arrayHats[index].life = true;
        bonus = bonus + 1;
      }
    }

 for (int index = 0; index < num_of_cones; index ++)            
    {       
      arrayCones[index].Draw();
      arrayCones[index].Move();  
      if (arrayCones[index].coneHit(Students.sx, Students.sy, sw, sh) == true)
      {
        if (arrayBoots[index].life == true)
         {
           arrayBoots[index].life = false;  // Removes extra life.
          } 
          else
          {
          gameScreen = 4;   //signifies game over.
        }
      }
    }
```

`

Comment: If you want to have multiple lives, why make it a boolean and not a number?

Comment: [Processing](https://processing.org/overview/) is a separate language by itself. It is not JavaScript. Although, it has a JavaScript implementation AFAIK (and Java, and Python) but I am not sure think tagging JavaScript is very useful. Tagging *only* JavaScript is definitely misleading.

Comment: I don't see where, in your code, the extra life boolean would be set to False (except for that part where you hit a cone). But the mistake may come from the way you handle the collision: if the cone still exists, you'll return true to a collision about 60 times per second, making it look like you had no extra life since it was used in the 1/60 first part of the second and you died on the 2/60 part of the collision. I'm pretty sure that it's the issue, although I can't read the whole code so I can't say for sure.

Comment: To test this hypothesis, you can println ou draw a dot when you have a extra life. If the extra life doesn't save you from instant death, I'm probably right. If the extra life disappear before the collision for another reason, you'll see it happen and will be able to look further in your code at what was currently going on when it disappeared.